# Portable Class Library Profile 78 missing attribute related methods/properties

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin, portable-class-library

In my PCL core project (WP8, Android, iOS, Xamarin, MvvmCross) I use custom attributes. The  Type.GetCustomAttributes() extension method lets me examine the attributes used.

Using PCL Profile104 this works well. But because I want to use async/await, I'll need to use PCL Profile78 (and .NET 4.5)

Problem: Seems the GetCustomAttributes() and the Attributes property are not available in Profile78. Why??

Note:
I am looking into the workaround by creating a PCL Profile 104 class library and wrapping the GetCustomAttributes() and then referencing this library from my PCL Profile78 library. However it seems extensionmethods are not supported...

Example Code:

```
public Pcl78Class()
{
    Type t = this.GetType();
    var attributes = t.Attributes;
    var customAttributes = t.GetCustomAttributes(true);

    // another weird thing: Why is VS CodeCompletion telling me it knows CustomAttributeExtensions class and methods?
    //System.Reflection.CustomAttributeExtensions.GetCustomAttributes(t);
}
```

[image]

Comment: This also occurs in Profile7

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Problem: Seems the GetCustomAttributes() and the Attributes property are not available in Profile78. Why??

[Profile78 includes support for Windows Store 8](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/05/framework-profiles-in-net.html) (as noted on my blog), and [Windows Store has a more efficient implementation of `Type`-based reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh535795%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Essentially, you just have to call `Type.GetTypeInfo` to get a `TypeInfo`, and from there it should be pretty straightforward.

Comment: Hey, I switched to System.Reflection.GetTypeInfo - but it's always returning null. I'm trying Profile49. Any suggestions?

Comment: @skimania: That's a different question than this one, so you should post it as a separate question. Then more people will see it and you'll get better answers.