# Type.GetMember & MemberInfo.GetCustomAttributes missing (C# PCL .NET 4.6)

Tags: .net, xamarin, portable-class-library

I am probably being really stupid here.

I have updated on of my solutions to start using .NET 4.6.  One of my PCL projects does some reflection on an enum.  I have updated the PCL compatibility, and fixed the empty project.json file it created.  However, this PCL project no longer builds as it doesn't recognise either `Type.GetMember()` or `MemberInfo[x].GetCustomAttribute(...)`

The code that I have been using, and was working until today is:

```
        MemberInfo[] info = e.GetType().GetMember(e.ToString());
        if (info != null && info.Length > 0)
        {
            object[] attributes = info[0].GetCustomAttributes(typeof(Description), false);
            if (attributes != null && attributes.Length > 0)
                return ((Description)attributes[0]).Text;
        }

        return e.ToString();
```

The project only references the .NET library which is in the following path:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETPortable\v4.5\Profile\Profile7\

The project has automatically supported Xamarin platforms too as part of the configuration of the PCL.

Any thoughts would be massively appreciated.

Comment: Is it profile 78?  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19741631/portable-class-library-profile-78-missing-attribute-related-methods-properties

Comment: @Jason It is just profile 7 - but I think this is likely to resolve the issue anyway.  Need to do a bit more testing to be sure, but at least it builds now :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, so this took a while (and forgot it was even a problem!!)

However the above comments pointed me in the right direction, with one big problem that it was trying to give me Attributes to the Class (main enum) rather than the enum elements themselves.  The link in the comment above took me to using `GetTypeInfo` in the first line of code, this had to be replaced to `GetRuntimeField`

A small tweak meant I ended up with something along the following lines:

```
public static string ToDescription(this ArtistConnection e)
{
    var info = e.GetType().GetRuntimeField(e.ToString());
    if (info != null)
    {
        var attributes = info.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(Description), false);
        if (attributes != null)
        {
            foreach (Attribute item in attributes)
            {
                if (item is Description)
                    return (item as Description).Text;
            }
        }
    }

    return e.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this David, really helped me out!